# Clicking hamburger icon on Toolbar does not open Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-optionsmenu, hamburger-menu

I have this **nav drawer** which was working perfectly fine. 
Refactoring my code I removed all `onOptionsItemSelecteds` in activities and made all activities inherit from a base activity which extends `AppComplatActivity` and **implements** all the necessary methods. 
After this clicking on hamburger icon does not work any more even though I have `syncstate`() and every thing.

**Any clues why this is not working?**

> One of the activities:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements SearchFilterFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

NavigationView navigationView;
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

private Tracker mTracker;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}

@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    mTracker.setScreenName("MainActivity" + "-----");
    mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view_primary);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationDrawerListener(this));
    setupToolbar();
    Haftdong application = (Haftdong) getApplication();
    mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
}

private void setupToolbar() {
    // Show menu icon
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);// will make the icon clickable and add the < at the left of the icon.
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();//for hamburger icon
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {
}
```

}

BaseActivity:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_base, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're using the four-parameter constructor for `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, which means you'll have to call the toggle's `onOptionsItemSelected()` method in `MainActivity`'s `onOptionsItemSelected()` override in order to open/close the drawer.

For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

---

If you happen to be providing your own `Toolbar` – e.g., as the support `ActionBar` (though it's not necessary to set it as such) – then you can instead pass that `Toolbar` as the third argument in the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` constructor call. For example:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
        toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
```

The drawer opening/closing will then be handled by `ActionBarDrawerToggle` internally, and you won't need to call through to the toggle in `onOptionsItemSelected()`.

The `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` call is also unnecessary for this setup, which is handy if you don't want to set the `Toolbar` as the `ActionBar`.