# How to get Toolbar menu icon (Drawer opening menu) click event?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I want to do some operation when i click the menu (not a overflow menu) in Toolbar. How to detect the event of click menu or Opening DrawerLayout?[image]

Comment: Jayadeep Patel onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) not called

Comment: If you've set the `Toolbar` as the support `ActionBar`, then you can remove the `Toolbar` argument from the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` constructor call, and setup the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method like is shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36570774. Inside the `if` block is where you'd put your additional code.

Comment: A simple fix would be to add an imageview into the toolbar with the hamburger icon as its src and then add an onclick listener to the imageview and perform you custom logic inside of the onclick method as well as programmatically toggle the navigation drawer.

Comment: Mike M Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // your stuff
    }
});
```

See also [Cannot catch toolbar home button click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582075/cannot-catch-toolbar-home-button-click-event)

Comment: lvBaranov setNavigationOnClickListener not called